# Icon in v-expansion-panel-header taking too much space

Tags: css, vuetify.js, accordion

I want to put a status indicator in my `v-expansion-panel-header`:

```
    v-expansion-panels
        v-expansion-panel
            v-expansion-panel-header Overview
            v-expansion-panel-content
                | ...
        v-expansion-panel
            v-expansion-panel-header(disable-icon-rotate)
                v-icon(color="success") mdi-check
                | Details
            v-expansion-panel-content
```

However, for some reason the icon is taking up almost all the room in the header:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

The [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels/#custom-icon) show an example with the check mark on the right hand side, by using `v-slot:actions`, but that had the same effect.

I note that there is a rule affecting the `i` of the icon:

```
.v-expansion-panel-header > :not(.v-expansion-panel-header__icon) {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Manually disabling that rule improves the situation:

[image]

Is there a way to do this properly?

Using Vuetify 2.5.8.

Answer (score 1):

you can construct a grid layout inside `v-expansion-panel-header` using `v-row` and `v-col` to achieve any desired layout you want in the header.

check the demo below:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        header: 'one',
        icon: null,
        iconColor: null,
        content: 'some text'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        header: 'two',
        icon: 'mdi-check',
        iconColor: 'green',
        content: 'some other text'
      },
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-expansion-panels focusable>
          <v-expansion-panel v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
            <v-expansion-panel-header>
              <v-row>
                <v-col v-if="item.icon" cols="1">
                  <v-icon :color="item.iconColor">{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="11">
                  {{ item.header }}
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
            </v-expansion-panel-header>
            <v-expansion-panel-content>
              {{ item.content }}
            </v-expansion-panel-content>
          </v-expansion-panel>
        </v-expansion-panels>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to put your icon and your text ("Details") inside a `<span>`. The stylesheet rule with flex (from vuetify) will try to spread out any child items. This is not a problem when you just have some text, but when you add an icon you suddenly have two child items that will then be spread out. By putting them in a span (or some other HTML element) you end up with only one child element that will then be shown at the left.